# Is there a way to shorten a series of colClasses

Tags: r

At the moment I am reading in a data file like this:

```
setwd("N:/HH Scallop Growth Project/Ring data by cruise/")

growth <- read.csv("Growth.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE,
                    colClasses=c("character","character","character","numeric",
                                 "character","numeric","numeric","numeric",
                                 "numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric",
                                 "numeric","numeric","character","numeric",
                                 "character","numeric","numeric","numeric",
                                 "numeric","character","numeric","numeric",
                                 "numeric"))
```

It works fine but it is a bit long/scruffy, is there a way of shortening/grouping the `colClasses`?

Comment: What if you don't specify the `colClasses` explicitly and only use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`? Does that result in wrong `colClasses`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a 25-vector whose entries are all `"numeric"` and then just replace the few that are not with `"character"`.  Also note that `header=TRUE` and `sep=","` are the default for `read.csv` so they can be omitted.

```
colClasses <- replace(rep("numeric", 25), c(1:3, 5, 15, 17, 22), "character")
growth <- read.csv("Growth.csv", colClasses = colClasses)
```

Answer (score 4):

What about the `rep` function:

```
R> rep(1:3, 2:4)
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

So something like

```
cc = rep(c("character", "numeric"), c(2, 4))
read.csv("Growth.csv", header=TRUE, colClasses=cc)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a list with lengths and values

```
xList <- list(lengths = c(3,1,1,9,1,1,1,4,1,3)
              , values = rep(c("character", "numeric"), 5))
```

then use `inverse.rle`

```
> inverse.rle(xList)
 [1] "character" "character" "character" "numeric"   "character" "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"  
 [9] "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "character" "numeric"  
[17] "character" "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "character" "numeric"   "numeric"  
[25] "numeric"
```